# bash: extract values into table

Tags: bash

I have ~200 text files, around 10Kb in size each, and all named `fastqc_data.txt`, each in a different subdirectory. The files were generated by a third party. The top of each file is shown below. My aim is to generate a new file, the first column of which will contain the "Filename" value (in this example "1265-H19_AGGCAG_L007_R1_001.fastq", the second column will contain the "Total sequences" value ("41284554"), and the third column will contain the value for "Sequence length" ("100").

Example input file 1:

```
FastQC 0.10.1  
Basic Statistics pass       
Measure        Value   
Filename        1265-H19_AGGCAG_L007_R1_001.fastq       
File type       Conventional base calls 
Encoding        Sanger / Illumina 1.9   
Total Sequences 41284554        
Filtered Sequences      0       
Sequence length 100     
%GC     41      
END_MODULE
```

Example output file:

```
Filename Total.Sequences Sequence.length  
1265-H19_AGGCAG_L007_R1_001.fastq 41284554 100  
1265-H20_TTTCAG_L007_R1_001.fastq 51387564 103  
1265-H21_CGGTTG_L007_R1_001.fastq 33254771 96
```

Comment: Is that the entire contents of one file? I guess not, if you say they're 10kb each.

Comment: It's not the entire file contents. More of it looks like:
Sequences flagged as poor quality       0      
Sequence length 100      
%GC     40   
>>END_MODULE   
>>Per base sequence quality     pass
#Base   Mean    Median  Lower Quartile  Upper Quartile  10th Percentile 90th Percentile
1       32.22927768362192       33.0    31.0    34.0    31.0    34.0
2       32.471828039631184      34.0    31.0    34.0    31.0

Comment: It's pretty much unreadable in a comment...the important thing to know is whether the lines you have shown are sufficiently unique. For example, are there any other lines in the file that start in the same way as the ones you're trying to match? Did you try the code in my answer, by the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transform your input into a row of output using an awk script like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "Filename Total.Sequences Sequence.length"}
     /^Filename/{fn=$2}
     /^Total Sequences/{ts=$3}
     /^Sequence length/{print fn,ts,$3}' input_file
```

The `BEGIN` block is executed before any lines of your file are processed. When the other patterns are matched, the fields are saved to the variables `fn` and `ts`, to be used later. When the final pattern matches, the line is printed.

Of course, this makes a number of assumptions, such as that all the files contain the data in the same order.

Depending on the details of your directory structure and assuming that your shell supports it, you may be able to pass all of the files to the script like `awk '...' **/fastqc_data.txt`. This uses the "globstar" shell feature to recursively match all files with the name `fastqc_data.txt` and pass them all to the awk script.

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much. As suggested, customising the directory path is the final simple step.